# Heroku Review Apps failed to create new instance when `env` is set in `app.json` file?

Tags: heroku, integration

First of all, recently I just try the [Review Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps) feature & notice an issue that the worker (or something that create new instance for review automaticaly) is always fails to create new server instance when I set `env` key in my `app.json` file.

Here my scenario.

1. Let's say I've already create new Laravel project & push it to heroku.
2. I create `app.json` file and add this line of codes

   ```
   {
     "name": "Laravel Project",
     "image": "heroku/php",
     "scripts": {
       "postdeploy": "php artisan migrate --force"
     }
   }
   ```
3. I create `Procfile` file and add this line

   ```
   web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C custom-nginx.conf -i custom-php.ini public/
   ```
4. Push latest changes to heroku & enable Review Apps feature to my pipeline
5. I create new branch that contain some fixes & make a pull request,
6. I see my pipeline automaticaly create new server instance for my pull request, but it's failed to deploy due to database configuration is not set yet.

   [image]
7. Now, I need to add [`env`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#env) key to my `app.json` and add my database configuration.

   ```
   {
     "name": "Laravel Project",
     "image": "heroku/php",
     "scripts": {
       "postdeploy": "php artisan migrate --force"
     },
     "env": {
       "APP_ENV": "staging",
       "DB_CONNECTION": "sqlite"
     }
   }
   ```
8. But, when I push it heroku couldn't create the new server instance & I can't see any error log or something that tell me information about what happen. I can only see **Create Review App** button on my pipeline

   [image]

   and, multiple *deployment request* on my github PR.

   [image]

There's something missing from my config? or anyone have solution for me?

Thanks & sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the problem here might be, that you use SQLite. Heroku's file system is read-only, so SQLite won't work. My tip would be to try a different DB like postgres for your review apps.